# Configuring python

Tags: python, memory

I am new to python and struggling to find how to control the amount of memory a python process can take? I am running python on a Cento OS machine with more than 2 GB of main memory size. Python is taking up only 128mb of this and I want to allocate it more. I tried to search all over the internet on this for last half an hour and found absolutely nothing! Why is it so difficult to find information on python related stuff :(

I would be happy if someone could throw some light on how to configure python for various things like allowed memory size, number of threads etc.

A link to a site where most controllable parameters of python are described would be appreciated well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forget all that, python just allocates more memory as needed, there is not a myriad of comandline arguments for the VM as in java, just let it run. For all comandline switches you can just run python -h or read man python.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the machine does not have a 128M process limit? If you are running the python script as a CGI inside a web server, it is quite likely that there is a process limit set - you will need to look at the web server configuration.